# итеративное добавление строки в конец другой

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

имеется код:

```
char *res;
char *buf;

res = (char*)malloc((num * 8 + 1) * sizeof(char));
buf = (char*)malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
```

`num` - количество байт.
Программа на вход принимает байты, преобразует их в двоичное представление с дополнением до длины 8  + символ конца строки. Это временное представления байта хранится в `buf`. Мне необходимо в `res` добавлять содержимое `buf` каждый раз в цикле в самый конец. 
К примеру первый байт: 01111001 - `buf` -> 01111001 - `res`;
          второй байт: 1001 1011 - `buf` -> 0111100110011011 - `res`.
Подскажите, как грамотно это реализовать?

Comment: Функция strcat как раз служит для добавления строки в конец другой строки.

Comment: А. да, точно, спасибо. Я уже хотел велосипед изобретать :)

Comment: Грамотно — не преобразовывать вообще. Когда понадобиться, тогда и делать сразу над всем массивом накопленных данных.